# Unique linux machine identifier for virtual machine migration scenario

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, uniqueidentifier

I want to make a licensing mechanism for my product which runs in linux. I need to generate a device id, and I don't want my product to run on another computer with the same license. Actually in physical environment this is not a problem. I can create a unique id using machine's hardware information. However, in virtual environment I could not find a proper way of creating a unique id for the virtual machine. When I do a migration via VMware, my generated id doesn't change. I always need to generate a different id for cloning and migration scenarios. I think the problem is I am using information related to VM not the host machine for generaring an id. How can I get some hardware information about host machine from VM? (Like serial number for host machine's CPU)

I used lots of commands like:

dmidecode -s system-serial-number

dmidecode -s system-uuid

lscpu

/proc/cpuinfo

/sys/class/dmi/id/board_serial

/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid

The id I generated is not changing when I migrate the VM to another platform. I know there are similar questions about this topic in stackoverflow, but none of them solved my problem.